# Invalid settings detected in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, hardware-acceleration

I am trying to set up a Linux Mint box on my new laptop (windows 10). After setting up a new virtual machine, I get the Invalid settings detected error, which says "**System: Acceleration page: The hardware virtualization is enabled in the Acceleration section of the System page although it is not supported by the host system. It should be disabled in order to start the virtual system.**"

To get help I followed this [IT World blog](https://www.itworld.com/article/2981515/virtualbox-diagnose-and-fix-vt-xamd-v-hardware-acceleration-errors.html). And I found that `vt-x` is already enabled in my bios, as suggested by CPU-Z. What to do next?

Comment: Disable Hyper-V in Host OS. And this command: `bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype off`.

Comment: @Biswapriyo how to disable Hyper-V? WIth the command you mentioned? Or it does something else? Also, disabling hyper-v won't have any bad effect, right? I am sorry if I sound too silly but I am a little noob at these areas.

Comment: No, it won't hurt anything.  I bet you can guess how to put it back. ;) I myself have two entries when my system boot to let me choose which one I want. Google it ;)